# How to stretch tileSprite to fullscreen in Phaser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sprite, phaser-framework

So, the question is: How to stretch tileSprite to fullscreen ?

```
planetSprite = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, game.width + 500, game.height + 900, planetObject.key + 'Planet');
// planetSprite.anchor.setTo(0, 0);
planetSprite.scale.set(0.75, 0.6);
planetSprite.fixedToCamera = true;
```

and here I have a problem:
it looks ok on my screen, but on bigger one this tileSprite is repeated
and also it's not stretched to fullScreen on bigger screens

image is attached
[image]

Thank you in advance, guys !!

Answer (score 0):

`sprite.scale` sets the scale of a sprite as a percentage of its actual dimensions, so a 1000 px-wide sprite with `scale.x` set to `0.75` will be 750 pixels wide on any screen.

My approach to this would be to set `sprite.width` as wide as `game.width`, then set `sprite.scale.y = sprite.scale.x` to keep aspect ratio.